# Push object into an array

Tags: javascript

I have requirement like need to form object as below

```
[
    {
      "place": "Royal Palace, Oslo",
      "latitude" : "59.916911"
    },
    {
      "place": "Royal Palace, Oslo",
      "latitude" : "59.916911"
    }
]
```

the above place and latitude values are available within map function as

```js
let sampleArray = [];
jsonresponse.map((item) => {
    let place = item.place;
    let latitude = {/*with other logic function we will get latitude value*/}
    //need to send these both values into below array to form array shown as above.
    sampleArray.push();
})
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question exactly ?

Comment: "How do I push an object into an array" is a little too basic for an SO question. The answer is: "Just do it." I mean, you even wrote the desired target array format down already. Weird question... Also, I fail to see _any_ connection to "react" or "react-native" - I removed those tags.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the map function wrong.
In a map function, you create a new array in which for each value the return value replaces the current value.
Your function isn't returning new values, and isn't pushing anything to the array. So you have 2 options:

```
//FIRST OPTION
const sampleArray = jsonResponse.map(({ place } => ({
    place,
    latitude: [SOME_VALUE]
}))

//SECOND OPTION
const sampleArray = [];
jsonresponse.forEach(({ place }) => {
    sampleArray.push({
        place,
        latitude: [SOME_VALUE]
    })
})
```

Also, notice the es6 destructuring syntax, it could save you some code.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do with Array.prototype.map is:

```
let sampleArray = jsonresponse.map((item) => {
    let place = item.place;
    let latitude = {/*with other logic function we will get latitude value*/}

    return {
      place,
      latitude
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to accomplish ?

```
let sampleArray = []
jsonresponse.map(item => {
  sampleArray.push({
    place: item.place,
    latitude: {/*with other logic function we will get latitude value*/}
  })
})

console.log(sampleArray)
```

Comment: @VenuuMunnuruu Look at the other responses, don't use `map` for this! 3Dos just asked to clarify what you want, you should not actually do what you did.